# Aggregate by count, keep all columns in Pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas, data.table

Here is an example pandas DataFrame:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({"id": [10, 10, 20, 10, 50, 50], 
                  "name": ["A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "C"]})
```

I will show what I want to do, using data.table in R:

```
x = data.table(id = c(10,10,20,10,50,50), name = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "C"))
x[, .N, by = list(name, id)]
```

Which outputs:

```
   name id N

1:    A 10 3
2:    B 20 1
3:    C 50 2
```

I can get something similar with Pandas, but I can't keep the id column:

```
x["name"].value_counts()
```

returns:

```
A    3
C    2
B    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get the length of each sub-group identified by `['id', 'name']`, and return the group key as index.

```
x.groupby(['id', 'name'], as_index=True).agg(len)

id  name
10  A       3
20  B       1
50  C       2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `groupby` on 'name' and 'id' and just `apply` `len` function:

```
In [232]:
x = pd.DataFrame({"id": [10, 10, 20, 10, 50, 50], 
                  "name": ["A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "C"]})
x.groupby(['id','name']).apply(len)

Out[232]:
id  name
10  A       3
20  B       1
50  C       2
dtype: int64
```